# How can I compare Product Sales to Total Sales?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a list of 5 products in my BigQuery data set:

| Product_Name | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1000 |
| B | 2000 |
| C | 3000 |
| D | 4000 |
| E | 5000 |

How can I get `%OutOfTotalSales`?

| Product_Name | Sales | %OutOfTotalSales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1000 | 6.67% |
| B | 2000 | 13.33% |
| C | 3000 | 20.00% |
| D | 4000 | 26.67% |
| E | 5000 | 33.33% |

I assume that I need to create an extra field, `TOTAL_GROSS`:

```
TOTAL_GROSS / PRODUCT_GROSS*100/TOTAL_GROSS
```

The question would then be: How can I get `TOTAL_GROSS` inside this expression?

**Sample**:

- Data Set ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zZk8KCfRhXRrDtS2dosdhXITxVnSNwwkTvQLaoK-R40/edit?usp=sharing))
- [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/499e91cf-684e-4cac-9af9-6653d611777b) report

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly then ideally you would do that calculation outside of Data Studio as Data Studio isn't really set up to do that automatically.

However if that isn't an option, you'll have to create a metric separately for each product which for product A would look something like:

```
sum(CASE WHEN Product_Name = 'A' then Sales Else 0 END)/sum(Sales)
```

To do the calculation in BigQuery you would do:

```
SELECT Product_Name, Sales, Sales/SUM(Sales) OVER () as %OutOfTotalSales
FROM you_table
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using the [comparison metric](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9372465), **Percent of total**:

### [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044)

- ***Dimension 1***: `Product_Name`
- ***Metric 1***: `Sales`

  - ***Aggregation***: [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212)
- ***Metric 2***: `Sales`

  - ***Rename***: `%OutOfTotalSales`
  - ***Aggregation***: [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212)
  - ***Comparison calculation***: Percent of total (Relative to corresponding data)

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/151df700-7632-474c-b71b-fa1593dcee51) report (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z8Jkxw0TCKo7rAOxsS2p1rhlZWvSmZeLgXRIzckDb2k/edit?usp=sharing) data source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: gif]